# If statement is not working in Python

Tags: python

I just got a Codeacademy Pro account and I got to make an Area Calculator. Because Codeacademy uses Python 2, I translated the code to fit the Python 3 standarts and I still get an error on line 7 - the if statement has an invalid syntax. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
"""This program calculates the area of a circle or a triangle."""

print("Area calculator starting up")

option = (input("Enter C for Circle or T for Triangle: ").lower()

if option == "c":
  radius = float(input("Enter circle's radius: "))
  pi = 3.14
  area = pi * radius ** 2
  print ("The area of this circle is : " + str(area))
elif option == "t":
  base = float(input("Enter the triangle's base: "))
  height = float(input("Enter the triangle's height: "))
  area = 0.5 * base * height
  print ("The area of this circle is: " + str(area))

else: 
  print ("Invalid shape!")

print ("The program is exiting!")
```

Comment: unbalanced parenthesis on `option = (input("Enter C for Circle or T for Triangle: ").lower()`
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies above the "if" section:

```
option = (input("Enter C for Circle or T for Triangle: ").lower()
```

should be :

```
option = input("Enter C for Circle or T for Triangle: ").lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra opening parenthesis `(` from line 5. It will solve your problem.
Your extra opening parenthesis expecting corresponding closing parenthesis `)`,because of not getting the parenthesis it's showing error on the next line.